# How to display information in UIPickerView when clicking on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

I've been looking and trying all the code examples provided for this issue, however i cannot seem to get it working. This is my first time making an app (besides from completing tutorials) so forgive me for asking a 'stupid' question. I'm just a newbie.

I'm trying to create an iOS App to register the starting & end time, the type of service and the customer. As soon as the user taps the UITextField the UIPicker pops-up displaying the information. 
I was able to create UIDatePicker for the start and end time, and an empty UIPickerView for service and customer.

The problem i've encountered is that i'm trying to add the names of the customers and the types of services to the UIPickerView for each. However so far without success. I've tried doing so with adding an array, but nothing shows up in the UIPickerView. In the storyboard i've added 4 lables and 4 UITextFields for each item.

The code for .h looks like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {
    UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    UIDatePicker *datePicker2;
    NSArray *dienstArray;
    NSArray *klantArray;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSArray *dienstArray;        //Service Array
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSArray *klantArray;         //Customer Array
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *dienstPicker;    //Service PickerView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *klantPicker;     //Customer PickerView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dienstTextField;  //Service TextField
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *klantTextField;   //Customer TextField
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dateSelectionTextField;   //BeginDate TextField
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dateSelectionTextField2;  //EndDate TextField

@end
```

This is the code of .m
    @interface ViewController ()
    @end

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize dienstPicker;
@synthesize klantPicker;
@synthesize klantArray;
@synthesize dienstArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //BeginDatumTijdPicker
    datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;

    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];       //Date notation 24hours
    [datePicker setLocale: locale];

    // Styling for the UIPickerView
    [self.dateSelectionTextField setInputView:datePicker];                              //shows the UIPickerView
    UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate1)];    //When clicked "Done" the UIPickerView disappears.
    UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
      [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,doneBtn, nil]];
        [self.dateSelectionTextField setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];

//EindDatumTijdPicker
// [Same as BeginDatumTijdPicker but different names]

        //DienstPicker

    dienstPicker =[[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    dienstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"test1", @"test2", @"test3", @".....", nil];
    self.dienstPicker.delegate = self;
    self.dienstPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.dienstPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    // Styling for the UIPickerView
    [self.dienstTextField setInputView:dienstPicker];               //shows the UIPickerView
    UIToolbar *toolBar3 = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [toolBar3 setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn3=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDienst)]; //When clicked "Done" the UIPickerView disappears.
    UIBarButtonItem *space3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [toolBar3 setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space3,doneBtn3,nil]];
    [self.dienstTextField setInputAccessoryView:toolBar3];


    //KlantPicker

    klantPicker =[[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    klantArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"test1.1", @"test2.1", @"test3.1", @".....", nil];
    self.klantPicker.delegate= self;
    self.klantPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.klantPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    // Styling for the UIPickerView
    [self.klantTextField setInputView:klantPicker];             //shows the UIPickerView
    UIToolbar *toolBar4 = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [toolBar4 setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn4 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedKlant)]; //When clicked "Done" the UIPickerView disappears.
    UIBarButtonItem *space4 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [toolBar4 setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space4,doneBtn4,nil]];
    [self.klantTextField setInputAccessoryView:toolBar4];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//ShowSelectedService (When clicking the "Done" button, the UIPickerView disappears. )

-(void)ShowSelectedDienst{
    [self.dienstTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

//ShowSelectedClient (When clicking the "Done" button, the UIPickerView disappears. )

-(void)ShowSelectedKlant{
    [self.klantTextField resignFirstResponder];

}

// The code below
// works just fine.
//DatePicker Begin tijd
-(void)ShowSelectedDate1 {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM HH:mm"];                  //formats date & time
    self.dateSelectionTextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    [self.dateSelectionTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

//!!DatePicker Eind tijd!!
//Same as DatePicker Begin Tijd.    
@end
```

I'm hoping everything is clear and that someone can help me. 
this is what the app looks like:

[When the Service textfield is clicked the UIPickerView pops up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fqaf.png)

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You can add a notification observer for your textfiled so that a method gets hit when your textfiled became first responder!!!!! You can also do it using a tap gesture,so when you tap on text field, your method gets hit!!!!

Comment: in the UITextField. for service its dienstSelectionTextField and for customer its klantSelectionTextField

Comment: so you want to display picker info in the textfield ?

Comment: Well, the UIPickerView currently pops up as soon as the textfield is tapped.  but the UIPickerView wouldn't fill with items that i've tried adding in an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems, that nowhere in your code you set the delegate and data source of the `UIPickerView`. Without them, the picker view doesn't know what to display and how to inform you that the user has selected something.

Please take a look here : [UIPickerViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html) and here [UIPickerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) and let me know if something is not clear or you run into trouble implementing these.

---

Here is an example :

```
@interface ViewController () <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> //#1

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPickerView *pickerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pickerNames;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;     //#2
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;   //#2

    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 50)];
    self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    self.textField.placeholder = @"What's your favourite programming language?";
    self.textField.inputView = self.pickerView;

    self.pickerNames = @[ @"Objective-C", @"Swift", @"Java", @"C", @"C++", @"Other"];

    [self.view addSubview:self.textField];
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDataSource

// #3
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    if (pickerView == self.pickerView) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// #4
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (pickerView == self.pickerView) {
        return [self.pickerNames count];
    }

    return 0;
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDelegate

// #5
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (pickerView == self.pickerView) {
        return self.pickerNames[row];
    }

    return nil;
}

// #6
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (pickerView == self.pickerView) {
        self.textField.text = self.pickerNames[row];
    }
}

@end
```

Okay, here are the interesting parts :

1. Here we declare that we will be conforming to `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocols. A protocol is in its basic a set of method headers. When you declare that you will conform to a protocol, you need to implement them (those that are required at least).
2. This is quite obvious, we tell the picker that we will be its delegate and datasource. If we didn't declare conformance to the protocols before, the compiler would start giving us errors here.

   3. This method from `UIPickerViewDataSource` will be called to know how many components should be displayed. A date picker has typicaly 3 components (day, month, year) for example.
   4. This method wants to know how many elements there will be in every component.
   5. This method is where you actually provide the texts to display to the user. You could also implement one of the other two variations of this method to provide either an attributed text or a totally custom view.
   6. This method gets called when the animation stops on a new item.

The checks for `pickerView == self.pickerView` are not needed in this example. I have added them, so that you'd know how to decide for which picker (as you have 4 it seems) to return the information needed. Ideally, this would need some further refactoring, as it is not the best idea to have cluttered delegates/data sources.

Comment: this is the code that i added. klantPicker.dataSource = self;
    klantPicker.delegate = self;
    
    dienstPicker.dataSource = self;
    dienstPicker.delegate = self;
is this the correct way? or am i totally off now?

Comment: Yep, but this is not nearly enough. You also have to make `self` conform to both protocols and implement their required methods. If you haven't worked with protocols yet, I'd suggest you read about them (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) as they are one of the core concepts of Cocoa. I can give you a more detailed example in the answer later today if you'd like :)

Comment: I tried adding self, but i kept on getting errors. I'll read in to the link you gave me. and off course i would like to get an detailed example that would be so great.

Comment: I've edited my answer, let me know if something needs further explanation.

Comment: thanks! i will look in to this. I indeed have 4 pickers. 2 of them are dates (begin&end) and working perfectly. The other two i cannot get to work. i provided the code for the date as an example to show how i was at going about the problem.

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot from my app. I've tried your code, but nothing is happening.

Comment: Well, your screenshot shows a picker view without delegate and datasource setup. Can you update your code to show how you changed it and implemented the protocols?

Comment: The screenshot is the result of the code that i posted. Indeed without the delegate and datasource. However after adding
 `klantPicker =[[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    klantArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"test1", @"test2", @"test3", @"test4", nil];
    self.klantSelectionTextField.inputView = klantPicker;
    self.klantPicker.delegate= self;
    self.klantPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.klantPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;`
there still are no changes.

Comment: As I said - you need to actually **implement** the 4 methods! Without them the `klantArray` and `klantPicker` have no way of knowing about each other. Did you already do that, and if so, can you please show how?

Comment: can i perhaps send you an message or e-mail? maybe that will be easier to show you what i've done so far?

Comment: Got it! Sorry it took a while. I added some comments and try to make everything a bit clearer. http://pastebin.com/zjvcMsUG

Comment: You **did not** implement the methods from the delegate and data source. I don't know how to emphasize it stonger. Just saying `pickerview.delegate = self` is not enough. If you conform to a protocol you **MUST** implement its methods. The ones marked #3 to #6 in my example.

Comment: My apologies, i thought i did. I updated the code. I can however not use the same code for customer because i get the following error: duplicate declarations of method 'numberOfComponentsInPickerView while i did change the names for the pickerView

Comment: Oh man. No offence, but you need to get down to basics and read some books or the docs. First of all the name of your variables has nothing to do with the method names defined in protocols, and you **cannot** change them. Secondly, you cannot have two method with same name in one class (parameter names are not part of signature). Lastly if you are a delegate to two (or more) `UIPickerView`s you don't implement the protocol twice - you need to account for it in the implementation. Did you read about protocols in the link provided before? Was anything not clear there?

Comment: Well. my bad. since the name for the pickerView you used in the example method was called pickerView i assumed i had to change it to the name i gave the UIPickerView for my own in the method. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problem :) I once where where you are now and had a lot of crazy questions and problems :] I used such naming for simplicity ;]

Comment: Everyone starts from scratch, i thought i would catch on to it fast. The naming was confusing for me this time, but now i know not to change everything. I broke the app. So i'm going to have to fix that first. I'll certainly have questions once its back up and running though. Can you be patient with me? =)

Comment: Well, not to spoil the party, but this is already getting out of the scope of the original question and lengthy discussions in comments are also discouraged in SO. If you run into other problems, ask another question - if not me, than surely someon will come around and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Not to be rude (since you spend a lot of time already) but the initial problem still isn't solved. But no problem, i'll delete this question and hope that i'll be able to find the solution. Thank you for your time i really appreciate it.

Comment: No, if there is something still wrong with the initial issue, then let's get it done. Its just that reverting the namings of the protocol methods and figuring out their implementations should be enough to get you going :)

Comment: I'm back, started from the beginning with the whole project (it broke down yesterday). It works, Thanks!